# Random Effects with count Models

Tags: r, stata, random-effects

I'm trying to do a hurdle model with random effects in either r or stata. I've looked at the glmmADMB package, but am running into problems getting it download in R and I can't find any documentation on the package in Cran. Is this package still available? Has anyone used it successfully to estimate a hurdle model with random effects?

Alternatively, is there a way to estimate this in stata? Is there a way to estimate random effects with any type of count data in stata?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Jennifer

Comment: Don't know about Stata, but the `cmp` package *might* be capable of this: http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0224  `glmmADMB` isn't on CRAN for technical reasons, it's on R-forge. See http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/ ... The `MCMCglmm` package can also do hurdle models with random effects.

Comment: BTW, do you have a *preference* for R or Stata?

Answer (score 4):

In Stata, `xtnbreg` and `xtpoisson` have the random effects estimator as the default option. You can always estimate the two parts separately by hand. See the count-data chapter of Cameron and Trivedi's Stata book for cross-sectional examples.

You also have the user-written `hplogit` and `hnlogit` for hurdle count models. These use a logit/probit for the first-stage and a zero-truncated poisson/negative binomial for the second stage. Also, a finite mixture model might be a nice approach (see user-written `fmm`). There's also `ztpnm.` All these are cross-sectional models.